# Obtain Remote linux Server IP address' using bash script via ssh

Tags: linux

I need to Obtain my remote Linux Server eth1 IP address using bash script through the ssh and i have following command:
/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 |  awk '{ print $1}'

but when i run :

spawn ssh -t  $user@$remote_host "/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 |  awk '{ print $2}' ; echo $ip "
it says can't read "1": no such variable
    while executing
"spawn ssh -t  $user@$remote_host "ip=`/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 |  awk '{ print $1}'` ; echo $ip ""
    (file "./ssh2.sh" line 11)

So could please help me with this issue.
Thanks

Comment: can you create a script in the remote server?

Comment: You have at least one typo in there, as one of your "$1"s has changed to a "$2".  Probably that's all that changed, but it would be best to double- (and then triple-)check to make sure there aren't any other typos..

Comment: Yes i can  create.

Comment: if you do: ssh $user@$remote_host /sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}' you get a good reply.

Comment: I checked every single variable.

Comment: when i ssh mauanlly and run this :/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}' it returns the ip but through script is not working.

Comment: the problem is the script. Try something like ip=$(ssh $user@$remote_host /sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'); echo $ip

Comment: #brigo I'm trying to do following :ip=$(expect -c "
       spawn ssh   $user@$remote_host /sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'  
       match_max 100000
       expect \"*?assword:*\"
       send -- \"$pass\r\"
       send -- \"\r\"
       expect eof
       "
       ) but it's not working the point is i dont wanna have prompt for password .

Comment: what about this one: ssh remote_host -l root "(ifconfig | grep 'inet addr' | grep -v 127.0.0.1| cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"

Comment: If you dont want promp for password use key authentication.

Comment: BTW, do you really think you are going to have `127.0.0.1` assigned to `eth1`?  That would be very unusual, and probably very broken.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `ip` instead of the deprecated `ifconfig`, and skip all the extra greps and cuts since awk can do that.

So a command like `ip addr show dev eth0 | awk '/^ +inet / {split($2,a,"/"); print a[1]}'`

In any case, most of your problem in your example commands have to do with the type of quotes you choose, and how bash evaluates them.

If you do something like `cfrancy@ws:~$ ssh root@srv01 echo "Hello $USER"` then the output you will see is `Hello cfrancy`, and not `Hello root` like you might expect.  Because you have used double quotes `"` around your command for the remote system, all the variables are evaluated **before** the command is sent.  The command `cfrancy@ws:~$ ssh root@srv01 echo 'Hello $USER'` will return `Hello root` since the `$USER` is evaluated on the remote site.  Of course you also need to switch around or escape your other quotes inside your compound command so things work out properly.

Anyway, keeping the quoting behavior in mind the command would probably do what you want.  though I think my solution that uses only `ip`, and `awk` is a better choice since I am only useing 2 programs instead of 4.

```
ssh -t $user@$remote_host '/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr:"| grep -v "127.0.0.1" | cut -d: -f2 | awk "{ print $1}"'
```

Comment: I'm holding out for them to figure out `ip` was a more annoyance than help and revert.